# Child should take height of min-heigth-parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got a flex wrapperdiv, two childs and a innerchild of the left child.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="inner-content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
  </div
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}

#left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 300px;
}

#inner-content {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .6);
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#right {
  background-color: green;
  width: 60%;
}
```

The height of `#left` should always be at least 300px; if the content of `#right` grows beyond 300px, `#left` should be equal to #right.

The height of the #inner-content should always be max of `#left` (so either 300px or equal to `#right`). If the content is bigger, a scrollbar should appear.

At the moment, the #inner-content does not show a scrollbar, because parent `#left` does only have a min-width.

How can I give `#left` a dynamic height (dependent of `#right`), and still force `#inner-content` to take that height instead of it's content height? I also made a [bin](https://jsbin.com/tabuzuleyu/6/edit?html,css,output) with current situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to absolute position the `inner-content` element, like this, and by doing that, you overcome the issue when using percent for height, where it normally needs to be set on each parent all the way to the body (or first element with a fixed height value)

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}
#left {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 300px;
}

#inner-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .6);
  overflow: auto;
}

#right {
  background-color: green;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="inner-content">
      Content<br><br><br>
      Content<br><br><br>
      Content<br><br><br>
      Content<br><br><br>
      Content<br><br><br>
      Content<br><br><br>
      Content<br><br><br>
      Content<br><br><br>
      Content<br><br><br>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
      Content<br><br><br>
      Content<br><br><br>
      Content<br><br><br>
      Content<br><br><br>
      Content<br><br><br>
      Content<br><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `align-items:stretch;` to your `#wrapper` and remove fixed height on `#right`.

Then #Right has always the same height than #left.
If you want to set a min-height to your element, set it to `#wrapper`.

Comment: The height of #right is just an example, the content does set the height. Only #left has a min-height (in my app it's min-height is `100vh`, so a minimum of the height of the viewport). I want left be the minimum of the viewport -or- as large as #right. So whatever big the #inner-conent is, the height of #left does not change.